# ING bank Netherlands closed account with negative balance

Tags: netherlands, banking

I'm a foreigner and on 12.1 I closed my ING orange account by MijnIng with last balance 0,60 eur. All went smoothly.

About a week later I got a letter "Afschrift Betaalrekening" and there were two fees from 14.1 of 2,95 eur. So the account was closed in debt of -2,35 eur. Is this okay or do I have to pay it? In the letter there are no instructions, support ends with "we can´t find your account".

Thank you for answer.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "is this okay"? Like, "is it OK not to pay it"? If this is the question, then I don't think anybody would be in a position to advise you to not pay a debt that you owe to a bank.

Comment: Not advising you not to try to pay but for such a small amount the bank will most likely write off the debt with no further action or adverse consequences to you